# Slice method is not consistent

Tags: javascript, slice

I've created a function to parse a string of text and look for a combination of key words.  The key words and their indexes are then captured and used later on to reassemble the full string from first to last keyword, including all words in between.  I'm using array.slice to pull the string from the array however it's inconsistent and sometimes requires incrementing\decrementing the second value in order to get the exact match.  I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkeohan/g7vdgg1a/4/ to demo it.

line 50 and 64 the ones where slice is being used and in one instance index+1 is used and the other index-1.  Both produce the same results, most of the time.

```
var phrase = (datafull.slice( (comparearray[0].index-1),        
(comparearray[comparearray.length-2].index+1) ) ).join(" ")


matchingString = (datafull.slice( (comparearray[0].index-1),
(comparearray[comparearray.length-3].index-1) ) ).join(" ")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: slice method is consistent your array is not

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo.. I tried not to take your comments to personally and refactored the code.  I didn't start all over again but I was able to make it more efficient...at least I think so...I also discovered that the discrepancy with matching the phrase had to do with including a space in the replace string...previously it was .replace(/\./g,' ').  Once i closed the parens it worked every time.  If there are any other suggestions for improving the code I'm all ears...

Comment: First of all, it's poor style to omit semicolons. I suggest you start there if you want serious programmers to read your code. Second, you are not splitting the text correctly. `example.replace(/\./g,' ')` causes double spaces to appear, and when you apply `split(" ")`, you end up with empty strings in `data`. You should use a regular expression to split the text.